# Angular2 documentation - Hierarchical Dependency Injectors ( Restore Service )

Tags: javascript, typescript, angular

This is beginners question..
I have been reading Angular2 documentation, I came across example in 
Hierarchical Dependency Injectors chapter where Restore service is used to
make save/cancel functionality available for editing.

This is the service:

```
export class RestoreService<T> {
   originalItem: T;
   currentItem: T;
 setItem (item: T) {
   this.originalItem = item;
   this.currentItem = this.clone(item);
 }
 getItem () :T {
   return this.currentItem;
 }
 restoreItem () :T {
   this.currentItem = this.originalItem;
   return this.getItem();
 }
 clone (item: T) :T {
   return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(item));
 }
}
```

I was so excited about it so I tried it myself!
First I'm setting the values like this:

```
ngAfterContentInit(){
     this.metadata = {
      languages: this.selected_languages,
      countries: this.selected_countries,
      international: false
     }
 }
 set metadata(metadata: CvMetadata){
      this._restoreService.setItem(metadata);
 }
 get metadata(): CvMetadata{
    return this._restoreService.getItem();
 }
```

After that I'm changing *metadata* properties values with ngModel 
for example:  `[(ngModel)]="metadata.languages[0]"`

**The question:**
 For my sruprise When I update the *metadata* property value with ngModel it works - the currentItem has changed and the orginalItem has not! What I do not understand is how is that possible? I thought that ngModel would use setter for setting the *metadata* properties. But the setter is called only once when I set the original data. How does the ngModel know that it should change only the currentItem not he originalItem?
Is this the black magic?

I know.. I only need someone to explain this, but unfortunately or fortunately there are only you guys!

Thanks!

Comment: `ngModel` doesn't `set/get` the `metadata` object itself. But the `languages[0]` item.

Comment: @Abdulrahman true can't argue with that, but that is not the source of my confusion. How does it change only the currentItem or.. moreover how does the RestoreService provide that functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RestoreService: it has two functions `setter` and `getter`;

**`setItem (item: T)`**  sets `originalItem`, clones it and save the clone to `currentItem`.

**`getItem()`**  just returns `currentItem` (the cloned item)

Now, `ngModel` gets the item `metadata` in order to get its property `languages`. So it will get `currentItem`. When `ngModel` sets a new property value, it doesn't need to `set metadata()`. it only need to set `languages` property inside `metadata`. So, it will get `metadata` again and sets the `languages` property.

[Here is a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/heQfzru4a0xO90uPFlRy?p=preview) hopefully it will help

**Another way of explaining it:**

```
this.metadata = {language:['english']}; // you set metadata, effectively setting originalItem and cloning it to currentItem

this.metadata.languages = ['arabic'];  // you get metadata "currentItem", set its property languages. Never actually setting metadata itself
```

**Note on the `clone` function:** the function `clone` in `RestoreService` is not cloning the object in a "practical" way. Because it uses JSON parser. See these question for more details and better cloning approaches: [122102](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/122102/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-clone-an-object), [728360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object)

Comment: I just tested it and you are right! This was the confusing part of it... "using getter for setting stuff", but when I think of it, it makes perfect sense now.  Thanks again for explaining it!

Comment: @ChakijsTerzētājs You are very welcome. I am glad to be of help.